# Check if record exists while registering user

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

In my Register controller - I have the following method to check if a record exists in another table before creating a user:

```
public function getCompanyDetails($id)
{
    $details = Company::where('company_id', $id)->first();
    return $details;
}


protected function create(array $data)
{
    $company_id = $data['com_id'];
    $company_details = $this->getCompanyDetails($company_id);
    
    if ($company_details == null) {
        return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->with('warning', 'We could not find the company');
    } else {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

However when the company record is not found. I'm getting the following error message:

> Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse as an array

I believe it's expecting a return of type user. But how can I redirect back to the registration page if the company is not found?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why don't you use [validation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#rule-exists)?

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden - i'm not sure its possible to check a field other than id in a different table using validation rules

Comment: @Davos98 Check my answer for example. You can use the `exists` rule for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the method `withErrors()`:

```
Redirect::back()->withErrors(['warning', 'We could not find the company']);
```

I however recommend you to use the validation rule `Exists` instead of having more queries and manually return a message. You can do it like so:

```
$request->validate([
  'company_id' => 'required|integer|exists:App\Company,id',
]);
```

Then you won't need the extra logic and the other method.

Source: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/validation#rule-exists

Comment: Cannot use object of type Illuminate\Http\RedirectResponse as array